# Grails wkhtmltopdf plugin: no pdf output

Tags: pdf, grails, plugins, wkhtmltopdf

i am trying use the Grails wkhtmltopdf plugin (https://github.com/quorak/grails-wkhtmltopdf), but i can't get a rendered pdf file. Only the gsp template is shown instead.

What I have done so far:

This is the link, which calls the action in the Controller:

`<g:link action="downloadQuestionnaire" id="${questionnaireInstance?.id}">Download questionnaire</g:link>`

This is the action in the Controller:

```
def downloadQuestionnaire = {
    def questionnaire = Questionnaire.get(params.id) 

    render( filename:"File ${questionnaire.id}.pdf",
    view:'/templates/pdf/_questionnaire.gsp',
    model:[questionnaireInstance: questionnaire],
    marginLeft:20,
    marginTop:35,
    marginBottom:20,
    marginRight:20,
    headerSpacing:10,
    )
}
```

_questionnaire.gsp is the template, which should be rendered as  pdf.

In config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.wkhtmltox.binary = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
```

and i checked, that wkhtmltopdf ist working correctly.

To my understanding of the wkhtmltopdf plugin, the template _questionnaire.gsp should be rendered as pdf available to download. 
But in my case, the gsp-template is shown with the data of the questionnaireInstance.
There are no error messages at all.

Any ideas, how to get the pdf output?

Answer (score 0):

add pdf: 'application/x-pdf' to grails.mime.types in Config.groovy

```
grails.mime.types = [
    all: '*/*',
    ....,
    pdf: 'application/x-pdf'
]
```

and try to call controller/action.pdf or custom your g:link tag into this

```
<g:link action="downloadQuestionnaire" id="${questionnaireInstance?.id}.pdf">Download questionnaire</g:link>
```

hope it help.